# How to pass transactions in multithreading

Tags: quarkus

I encountered such a situation, I need to insert a batch of data into multiple tables in the database, this process can be a very time-consuming operation, so I think to use multithreading to improve efficiency, but also to ensure transactional, if a thread insertion error, other threads need to roll back, only all threads do not make mistakes before committing.
But I ran into transaction issues while coding, and I didn't know how transactions were shared between multiple threads in quarkus and hiberna-orm frameworks. I looked at the two guidelines for https://quarkus.io/version/3.2/guides/context-propagation and https://quarkus.io/version/3.2/guides/transaction
I found that transaction passing can be done in the Context Propagation extension, but I am not familiar with Mutiny and have tried to do it the Mutiny way, but not the way I expected (each thread is responsible for a batch of data). Is not in the https://quarkus.io/version/3.2/guides/transaction guidelines
Mentioned how the transactions, but also try QuarkusTransaction.com MIT ()/the begin ()/rollback (); TransactionManager tm; Are independent affairs.
So I used CountDownLatch to control the commit or rollback of these individual transactions.
I provide a simple piece of code to illustrate my situation.

```
    public void concurrency(){
    //start async update
    completableFuture = CompletableFuture.runAsync(this::asyncUpdate).handle((ret,throwable) -> {
        log.error(throwable.getMessage());
        return null;
    });
    System.out.println("response finished");
}

public void asyncUpdate(){
    AtomicBoolean hasException = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    //Control transaction commit or rollback
    CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(2);
    //task one
    CompletableFuture<Void> asyncUser = managedExecutor.runAsync(
                    () -> QuarkusTransaction.requiringNew()
                            .exceptionHandler(throwable -> {
                                log.error("transaction A rollback:{}", throwable.getMessage());
                                return TransactionExceptionResult.ROLLBACK;
                            })
                            .run(() -> {
                                try {
                                    try {
                                        // Simulate a very time-consuming insert operation
                                        userDao.update("set name = 'test' where id = 1");
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        countDownLatch.countDown();
                                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                    }
                                    countDownLatch.countDown();
                                    countDownLatch.await();
                                    if (hasException.get()) {
                                        log.error("task is have a exception");
                                        throw new RuntimeException("rollback");
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    hasException.set(true);
                                    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }))
            .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                log.error("asyncUser exception:{}", throwable.getMessage());
                return null;
            });
    //task two
    CompletableFuture<Void> asyncOrder = managedExecutor.runAsync(
                    () -> QuarkusTransaction.requiringNew()
                            .exceptionHandler(throwable -> {
                                log.error("transaction B rollback:{}", throwable.getMessage());
                                return TransactionExceptionResult.ROLLBACK;
                            })
                            .run(() -> {
                                try {
                                    try {
                                        //Simulate a very time-consuming insert operation
                                        orderDao.update("set userName = 'test' where id1 = 11");
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        countDownLatch.countDown();
                                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                    }
                                    countDownLatch.countDown();
                                    countDownLatch.await();
                                    if (hasException.get()) {
                                        log.error("task is have a exception");
                                        throw new RuntimeException("rollback");
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    hasException.set(true);
                                    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }))
            .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                log.error("asyncOrder exception:{}", throwable.getMessage());
                return null;
            });
    //await task one finished and task two finished
    CompletableFuture.allOf(asyncOrder, asyncUser).join();
    log.info("--------------------------");

}
```

Is there a better way to implement multiple threads sharing a transaction?

Comment: Check the guide for reactive Panache: https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-reactive-panache

Comment: I checked this guide and didn't use reactive Panache in my project